# Foggy, Snowy, Type effect in Unity3D

Tags: effects, unity-game-engine

How would you go about creating the effects of a blizzard in Unity3D?  Take the cliffhanger level in COD MW2 as an example.  I want it to limit the view of the player, and look like there is snow blowing around.

Thanks,
Tate

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/ would be a better place. (And even SO-engine powered :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'll sign up with them right now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:

In Unity's [render settings](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-RenderSettings.html), you can make adjustments to the fog.  Dense, whitish fog will limit visibility.

Falling snow particles (perhaps just in a renderer that stays right in front of the camera to help limit the number of particles) should help complete the effect.